# use of FOPLRelationalModel.MySQLMassLoader

Tags: python-2.7, rdf, rdflib

I am trying to use FOPLRelationalModel.MySQLMassLoader from rdflib but when I use,it shows

```
       /usr/bin/python: No module named rdflib.store.FOPLRelationalModel.MySQLMassLoader
```

I have tried installing rdfextras also but that is also not helping.The rdflib version is 4.2.0
Can anyone please tell me what should be done here

Comment: looks to me as if you're trying to combine an rdflib 2.4.0 rdflib extras feature with rdflib 4.2.0... https://github.com/RDFLib/rdfextras/tree/master/rdfextras/store/FOPLRelationalModel doesn't have a MySQLMassLoader anymore

Comment: then what is the best way to connect to a database in postgres or Mysql with rdflib 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to have a look at [RDFLib SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-sqlalchemy).

It allows you to connect to various databases like mysql, postgres, sqlite... and use them as a `Store` backend of `rdflib`.

Comment: now i am using  RDFLib SQLAlchemy.But can I insert rdf file content into postgres.I can not find that in the documentation